# What is the relationship between the three "Clone Wars" properties?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars, clone-wars-2003

There are three Star Wars animated properties dealing with the clone wars:

- [Star Wars: Clone Wars (2003 TV series)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars%3a_Clone_Wars_%282003_TV_series%29)
- [Star Wars: The Clone Wars (2008 film)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars%3a_The_Clone_Wars_%28film%29)
- [Star Wars: The Clone Wars (2008 TV series)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars%3a_The_Clone_Wars_%282008_TV_series%29)

**What is the relationship between these three**? Do they overlap or contradict each other? Do you need to have seen one of them before the others will make sense?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is canonicity of derivative works determined for Star Wars?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars)

Comment: Not really. This question is about the relationship between 3 properties with the same name, not about their canonicity.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Star Wars: Clone Wars (2003 TV Series)**

This was a limited series of "micro episodes". Each was a short (or "micro") story featuring one or two characters and their actions between Star Wars Episode 2: Attack of the Clones and Star Wars Episode 3: Revenge of the Sith. It primarily dealt with the Jedi, Padme and the droids. The first season featured no spoken dialog. The stories were not meant to be fully realized arcs, just snippets into the universe created to get people excited about the then-upcoming movie (Episode 3).

**Star Wars: The Clone Wars (2008 Film)**

When screening early footage of the 2008 TV series, the studio heads were so impressed that the decision was made to turn the first few episodes into a theatrical film and release it. It immediately precedes the series and is 100% in continuity with it.

**Star Wars: The Clone Wars (2008 TV Series)**

This was a long running series featuring many characters and their actions between Star Wars Episode 2: Attack of the Clones and Episode 3: Revenge of the Sith. These are more traditional full-length episodes. In addition to the Jedi, Padme, and the droids, it featured many of the Clone Troops and dealt heavily with the Sith. The characters and stories are fully realized. While some of the scenes and timeframes overlap with the original series of a similar name, the stories are independent. There is no required additional viewing or expectation of knowledge, but it certainly doesn't hurt.

---

Also, there's a difference in the canonicity. Under the new Disney canon rules, only the 2008 items are part of the New Canon, whereas 2003 TV series is not (it's unspecified yet if it's Legends, but probably is)

Comment: So is it safe to say that the two series are in the same continuity /canon?

Comment: @SystemDown I have admittedly (and sadly) not finished watching all of the 2008 Clone Wars show, but everything I have seen and read puts them in the same canon and continuity. Nothing directly contradicts each other, just fills in bits here and there.

Comment: @SystemDown - also, they are all T-canon, in terms of "legalese" :)

Comment: There are many relatively minor continuity changes in the later show, but most people won't notice.

Comment: Thank you! That was awesomely clear and I am now no longer confused.

Comment: The 2008 Film and TV Series are now on netflix. They don't overlap there; The film precedes season 1.

Comment: And the Clone Wars Film and TV series are now considered the only fully canon properties, alongside the 6 feature films and Star Wars : Rebels.

Comment: And whatever books have been released since late spring of 2014.

Comment: I'd always wondered this myself. Seems like we can safely ignore the cartoon version, but the CGI ones are a must-have. Or fun to watch, at any rate. I'm too old to memorize 30 more years of expanded universe.

Comment: To be clear:  after the Disney buyout and canon reboot, the 2003 series is no longer canon.

Comment: What part of "Under the new Disney canon rules, only the 2008 items are part of the New Canon, whereas 2003 TV series is not (it's unspecified yet if it's Legends, but probably is)" needed to be cleared up?

Answer (score 0):

1. 2003 showed the most important parts of the war.
2. The 2008 film is part of the 2008 tv series. (described below)
3. The 2008 Tv Series is an anthology, meaning events take place out of order for example there is an episode in season 1 that takes place in between 2 episodes in season 3. Also while the movie came before the show the movie takes place after a few of the first episodes of the show.