# Are Midi-chlorians able to be infused or transplanted?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

The more questions about the Force I read in here, the more Midi-chlorian count is used as a reference. As I understood, Midi-chlorians are the measurement for the Force power level of one user.

As I remember, they are microscopic life-forms in the red blood cells that *talk spiritually* to the user.

This then leads me to a question, if it is possible to give someone else an infuse of blood with Midi-chlorians. That then leads me to another questions. What happens if you use Force blood to rescue someone without it? Do already-infused get stronger? As I only know the films and very few other cannon material (games), I have to ask you:

**Are Midi-chlorians able to be infused to another body and do they have an impact to that another being?**

Comment: As I understand it though, midi-chlorians aren't the source of Force power, but simply an indicator of it. So transfusion would just lead to someone appearing to be powerful when tested, but not actually gaining any powers.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Yes, this is covered by option (1) in my answer.

Comment: [Completely and utterly uncanonical, but...](http://darthsanddroids.net/episodes/0086.html)

Comment: Lance Armstrong would make the best Sith.

Comment: If you could get Force powers by injecting/infusing Midichlorians, they would become the galaxy's most prized possession.  Wars would be fought over them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**TL;DR**: They are able to be transfused, but not in enough amount to affect Force Sensitivity and not permanently.

---

Midi-chlorians aren't contained in the blood per se (blood was merely used to TEST for the Midi-chlorian density as the easiest body part to test).

Midi-chlorians are [**part of ALL living cells**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian) in the organism (including blood).

While that is supported in canon, it also has support outside canon - the [inspiration](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian#Origins) for Midi-chlorians were of course the [Mitochondria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrion):

> Mitochondrion (plural mitochondria) is a membrane-bound organelle found **in most eukaryotic cells**

As such:

- Most Midi-chlorians in Jedi body are NOT found in the blood (which contain a very small portion of body's cells (20% according to [this Biology.SE answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/a/29858/185))
- Thus, giving someone else an infusion of Midi-chlorian-rich blood will only raise their Midi-chlorian count by relatively low amount compared to count of Midi-chlorians in a Jedi body.
- Since Force Sensitivity is determined by **total** Midi-chlorian body count, you can't become a real Force-sensitive by merely transfusing yourself with Jedi blood.
- Moreover, as far as I'm aware, the blood cells constantly die and are replenished with new ones<sup>*[biology.SE citation needed*]</sup>. This means that as time from transfusion goes on, there will be less and less Midi-chlorian rich cells in your blood, further reducing even the miniscule amount you got from transfusion.

Comment: Well, if you want a biologist's point of view, if midichlorians follow the same pattern of distribution as mitochondria (BIG if), then the greatest (or among the greatest anyway) concentration will actually be in sperm. Make of that what you will.

Comment: @terdon - I call rule34

Comment: So theoretically, you could engineer a retrovirus to insert midichlorian DNA into the host's cells. Like the common cold, but everyone who gets it becomes a Force prodigy. This would have some rather drastic and un-Star-Wars-ish social effects but it would be interesting...

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit - possibly, but unlikely. They don't seem to have THAT level of bioengineering in TGFFA; hell they need Bacta to do pretty much any reasonably advanced medicine.

Comment: @DVK: No argument there. I'm just saying it might be theoretically possible. And hey, it's a big galaxy and all you need is one reasonably advanced planet to decide that playing around with biotech would be a fun thing to do. :-)

Comment: @terdon Hence the old Jedi pick up line, "Hey baby do you have the force in you? No? Do you want some?"

Comment: Except midi-chlorians are not the source of force powers...

Answer (score 17):

**In Disney Canon**

This is unknown. We never see anyone receive a blood transfusion from any Force-User to a Non-User

**In Legends Canon**

Probably no. In [*The Eyes of Revolution*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Eyes_of_Revolution), General Grievous receives a blood transfusion using stored blood of Sifo-Dyas and does not gain any Force sensitivity or capabilities.

As [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Grievous) explains:

> **Dooku provided blood from the frozen body of Jedi Master Sifo-Dyas as a means of keeping Grievous's body alive during his transit to Geonosis**, where Poggle the Lesser and his Geonosian scientists implanted his brain and eyes into a duranium alloy body reminiscent of a Krath war droid, complete with LX-44 robotic legs. His vital organs were housed in a synthskin gut-sack impervious to vacuum. The Geonosians would also alter his brain against his wishes, both to trim away disturbing memories—while enhancing his rage centers—and to enhance his equilibrium, allowing him to better employ his newfound agility. Internal implants were also placed in his eyes to sharpen his vision and to protect them from the vacuum of space. **While the midi-chlorian-rich blood of Sifo-Dyas may have played a critical role in maintaining Sheelal's life, Grievous saw it as a personal failure that the transfusion did not also give him a degree of sensitivity to the Force.**

It is not explained (here, at least) exactly why Grievous thought the blood transfusion would grant Force Sensitivity. Whether Grievous had seen this work before, or if his race (Kaleesh) had something to do with it is not addressed.

Comment: Maybe Midi-chlorians die when frozen? :D But then they wouldn't be so important for saving Sheelal. Okay, this seems legit!

Answer (score 8):

Book Of Sith, Page 132, by Darth Plagueis: "a simple blood transfusion is the obvious answer, but I have found that the subject’s native midi-chlorians will reject the influx of foreign cells"

So no blood transfusion would not work.

Answer (score 8):

**Legends Answer**

This basically supports [DVK's TL:DR](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/49594/23879).

*Plagueis, pg 67-68*

> Research had long ago established that blood transfusions from Force-sensitive individuals did not confer Force powers to recipients, though blood with a high midi-chlorian count could grant temporary strength and resiliency. **Experiments in absolute transfusion had gone horribly awry for recipients**, suggesting to some that the Force exacted a toll on those who attempted to tamper with it. An individual's midi-chlorians seemed to know to whom they belonged and become unresponsive outside their dedicated vessel.

*See [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/80098/23879) for the difference between Canon, Legends, and non-canon.

Answer (score 4):

Going only by the films, I think we can safely assume that midichlorian transfusions don't work.

Imagine the possibilities if they **did** work. As you say, one could turn normal people into Jedi, or Jedi into much more powerful Jedi, with a transfusion of blood from Yoda, Mace Windu, or whoever. The Jedi certainly could use the extra numbers; in Espisodes I and II, we repeatedly hear that they are too few to effectively keep the peace in the galaxy. Furthermore, Qui-Gon would not be nearly so excited about discovering Anakin if powerful Jedi could simply be manufactured on demand.

We don't see this occur, therefore there is some reason why they don't do it. Possibilities are:

1. It doesn't work. The transfused midichlorians die off or fail to provide Force ability in the new host.
2. It works, but it has a negative effect on the physical or mental health of the recipient.
3. It works, but the boost is so short-term that it's not considered worth it. (One could imagine Jedi carrying vials of high-midichlorian blood for emergencies, but maybe the midichlorians don't live long enough once they are separated from their original host?)
4. It works, but there is a law or custom against doing it. Perhaps the senior Jedi do not **want** to share their power with anyone!

We don't really know but (1) is the simplest explanation, so by Occam's Razor it is fair to consider it the correct one.

(Out of universe, midichlorians weren't mentioned at all in Episodes IV-VI. They were one of the many things that fans really disliked in Episode I, so Lucas quietly dropped them in Ep II and Ep III.)

Comment: Yes, your numberation covered all thoughts I had, too. And just for 5.: "They didn't invented blood transfusion yet." So there is no cannon material that these things had been tested? --- btw i disliked them, too.

Comment: They have interstellar travel, so it seems unlikely they haven't invented the syringe, which is all you need for a blood transfusion. Doing a *safe* transfusion in our world requires knowledge of blood types, which might be problematic in a multi-species galactic civilization, but then we're back to option (2). And I agree the midichlorians were a bad idea; they result in people asking exactly this sort of question, which is not really in keeping with the fantasy/mystical feel of the Star Wars movies.

Comment: Reminisque that some invention where pure fortune. Otherwise... why should Lucas mention transfution, when it's naturally. But yes, I minded your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe.  General Grievous had not enough living flesh to EVER be force sensitive.  If someone had just under the midi-chlorian count required to use the force, a blood transfusion may TEMPORARILY help them.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this? We generally prefer answers here to be backed up by canonical sources or solid reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

While it may be true that midichlorians cannot be transferred from one genetic individual to another, it is unclear whether or not it's possible with identical genetic individuals i.e. Clones or twins etc. As shown in the tv show Star Wars The Clone Wars the Nightsisters *MAKE* Nightbrothers so by technicality they are using a different method for the same result as what Darth Plagueis attempted to do.

Comment: Does this answer the question of whether Midi-chlorians are able to be infused or transplanted? It seems more like you're wondering about a similar question and have a related comment.

Comment: What I was attempting to say at the time was that yes Midichlorians can be transplanted but 1) you need the original individual and the recipient to have a currently unknown factor (like blood types for blood transfusions and organ transplants) 2) the individuals must both have midichlorians already otherwise you are giving them to a corpse and 3) cloning is new to the galaxy so any research into the topic was done *before* they knew cloning was a thing.

Comment: Keep in mind that midichlorian count is just an indicator of how well one *could* control the force but, getting more midichlorians won't necesarily make you more powerful than someone who is trained just means that you have a higher potential.