# Do bionic implants interfere with force abilities?

Tags: star-wars

I can't remember where, but it was stated or heavily implied that droids cannot be force-sensitive due to their bionic nature (and also because they can't have midichlorions in their 'bloodstream').

Luke has his arm chopped off and replaced with a bionic hand, and Vader is "more machine than man' by the time he and Luke fight.

Do these bionic implants impede their ability to use the Force at all?

Comment: To my knowledge/recollection, most of the other discussions centered on the fact that droids  could not be force sensitive because blood transfusions did not impart any ability.

Comment: Very much related, but possibly not a dupe: [When Jedi lose parts of their body, does their midi-chlorian count and strength in the Force diminish?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4097/when-jedi-lose-parts-of-their-body-does-their-midi-chlorian-count-and-strength/4101).

Comment: @phantom42 Very similar, but I'm also curious if there's a de-humanizing factor that actively reduces force ability.  Which I think is interesting enough to explore further.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I think it's a good question and not a dupe.

Comment: Here's the question I was thinking of about the transplanted midichlorians: [Are Midi-chlorians able to be infused or transplanted?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/49583/are-midi-chlorians-able-to-be-infused-or-transplanted?)

Comment: I don't have a source, though I'm pretty sure it was from some material related to RotS, but I remember reading that because of his bionic hands, Vader couldn't cast Force lightning.

Comment: General Grievous ?

Comment: @Lighthart I don't think he could actually *use* the force, just several lightsabers off of force-users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canon is uncertain in this point. The only major being with massive implants and the force is Vader. The Emperor certainly thinks that Vader's connection to the force is deminished through his injuries. But the Jedi do not when he losses his arm on Geonosis. It also differs in HOW you think the force is expressed. A more mystical approch says no. There are sentiant force using Crystals that live in a droid body and use the force just fine. Someone's spritual connection can be nurtured and grown through ways like the Jedi use. Forcee ability is documented to grow through training and use. The other way is more scientific. The amount of midichlorians in a person determines force ability. But it is never clarified if it's per cell or the whole body or even if it's capible to change. Lucus seems to change his mind in that it starts out as more mystical in the original trilogy and more scientific in the prequels.

In total, it's how you personally view what the Force is and how it's expressed that will determine whether or not force ability can be deminished through loosing body parts. The Force is the perfect mind of matter situation. It is entirely possible that if you think it dimishes your ability, it will.

Comment: Darth Maul had his *entire* lower half replaced by cybernetics. [Valin Draco](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Valin_Draco) also had "massive" cybernetic enhancements. So Vader was not the *only* one. The Sith lady [Lumiya](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lumiya) would certainly agree with your point though.

Answer (score 1):

The force flows through all living things and can not be judged by the size of the user so if you as the force user believes  that the implants diminish your abilities then they will but they don't have to. Droids are not living so the force can not flow through them

Comment: It would be good to add some references to your answer