# Would a Jedi (Sith) clone be force-full or force-less

Tags: star-wars, the-force, clones

Just seen a picture of Vader Force-choking a trooper. And then I started wondering: what if they had cloned a Sith (or a Jedi). Would the clones have the Force? Specifically, would they have the **same** Force as the original?

Comment: I'm sure they'd have the same midichlorian count, so I don't see why they wouldn't have teh same power with the Force.

Comment: How is the first paragraph related with the second paragraph?

Comment: @MyCodeSucks ... wouldn't you run out of Midichlorian's? :P

Comment: Troopers are all clones of Jango Fett (who didn't have the force).

Comment: A trooper/victim not being Force Sensitive has nothing to do with why a Jedi/Sith doesn't use the Force to snap their necks.

Comment: The answer to that question says that a Force user cannot snap the neck of another Force user because the latter has the Force. I guess the same would apply with choking: a Sith could not choke a Jedi. But he could easily choke a trooper. Can we focus on the answer :)

Comment: "One would imagine, therefore, that snapping the neck of a Force-sensitive individual would be considerably harder,". Not the same as saying it can't be done, or that it's a boolean distinction.

Comment: Again, we are not debating about force-choking. That's just what made me thing troopers are Force-less. Please stay on topic.

Comment: @algiogia you should probably re-word the question to remove the first paragraph. Specifically, you just want to know if a clone of a Force user will have equal or similar Force ability.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Within G/Disney-Canon, this has never been tested. It can be noted, however, that [midichlorians cannot be transplanted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/49583/5184) in the EU/Legends canon.

However, this has come up a few times in the EU/Legends canon.

A few notable ones off the top of my head:

- [The Dark Empire comics](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Empire) deal with the Emperor being revived via clone bodies. Each are very powerful Sith/Force Users.
- [Joruus C'baoth](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Joruus_C%27baoth) - the clone of a Dark Jedi, created by the emperor. The clone is a powerful Dark Jedi with full access to the Force.
- [Luuke Skywalker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Luuke_Skywalker) - a clone of Luke, created by Joruus, using cells from Luke's severed hand. Luuke is a formidable opponent and Force User.
- [Starkiller](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Starkiller_%28clone%29) from the *Force Unleashed* games, who is a clone of Galen Marek. Like Marek, he has full use of Force Abilities, and is arguably stronger than the original (though, some of this is likely just due to heroes of sequel games needing to seem stronger than previous iterations).

Comment: I know next to nothing about EU/Legends, but I'm pretty sure I've read before on this site about some pretty important story lines involving a clone of Luke Skywalker?

Comment: Don't forget Luuke Skywalker (Jorus' clone of Luke) as well as Dorsk 82.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Ah, yes. [Luuke Skywalker](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Luuke_Skywalker). Forgot about him. Will add in a moment.

Comment: In the question you linked someone suggests the midichlorian are something similar to the mitochondria, hence something that is part of the cell. That means that clones **will**  have the same midichlorians. All the examples you have posted seem to confirm this.

Comment: Provided that it's an exact, unaltered clone, yes. But all examples of this are EU/Legends canon. Whether this is all true for Disney canon remains to be seen.

Comment: The Khommites are all clones, and it turned out that the entire line of Dorsk clones were Force-sensitive.

Comment: Wait, star killer is a clone? What?

Comment: @cde details here: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Starkiller_%28clone%29

Comment: Ugh. Force unleashed TWO not Force Unleashed.

Comment: The EU/Legends [CrossCurrent](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Crosscurrent) duology also deals with a storyline involving the discovery of a "Jedi-Sith cloning project" where the clones of Force users were themselves also Force users.

Comment: @Omegacron He's 81 not 82

Comment: @IG_42 the original featured in the Jedi Academy books was 81. After he died, his successor Dorsk 82 joined the Praxeum as well. That was when they figured out that the entire line was Force-sensitive, rather than Dorsk 81 being unique for some reason.