# Why Didn't Palpatine just Clone Anakin?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious

After Palpatine became Chancellor, why not hedge his bets by getting DNA from Anakin and secretly cloning an army of super-Force-sensitive warriors pre-programmed to serve only him? A Sith master must always worry about their apprentice turning on him, and the Kaminoans were shown capable of programming genetic orders into their clones that could not be disobeyed. Plus, the Anakin Clone Army could be ready in about 10 years which would not be too long for his plans.

Comment: I've wondered about why the Kaminoans didn't use a force-sensitive as their template for the clones...I don't know if this is addressed in canon, but you could speculate that being force-sensitive inherently conflicts with whatever genetic programming they use to make clones less likely to rebel against orders.

Comment: related: [Would a Jedi (Sith) clone be force-full or force-less](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/84641/5184)

Comment: Also related: [Are Midi-chlorians able to be infused or transplanted?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/49583/21267) and [When Jedi lose parts of their body, does their midi-chlorian count and strength in the Force diminish?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4097/21267)