# What happens to a Sith Lord's midi-chlorians after a transfer essence?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, the-force, sith

When a Sith essence transfers, do they lose their ability to use the Force? I would assume so, because their midi-chlorians would be left behind, wouldn't they? If a Sith Lord used clones, as many Sith did, they wouldn't be able to use the Force, would they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Midi-chlorians exist in the cells of *all* living things, including clones:

> Midi-chlorians are a microscopic lifeform that reside within all
>   living cells and communicates with the Force...Without the
>   midi-chlorians, life could not exist, and we would have no knowledge of the
>   Force. They continually speak to you, telling you the will of the Force.
>
> <sub>**Qui-Gon Jinn, *Star Wars:* Episode I *The Phantom Menace***</sub>

One's strength in the Force is determined by the concentration of midi-chlorians in one's body, and evidently a clone body contains the same concentration of midi-chlorians as the original since there are numerous examples of Force-sensitive clones (such as Palpatine's clones, [Set Harth's clones](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Set_Harth#Legendary_explorer), and [Galen Marek's clone](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Starkiller_%28clone%29)). Consequently, a Sith who transfers his essence from his original body to a clone of his own body would have the same Force strength as before, despite the fact that his original body and its midi-chlorians would be destroyed by the process. His connection to the Force would be through *different* midi-chlorians.

Every instance of a Sith attempting an essence transfer has either been into one of his own clone bodies (e.g. Palpatine) or into another Force-sensitive individual (Darth Bane, for example, who attempted to transfer his essence into his apprentice, Darth Zannah). Either way, the new body would have a high enough concentration of midi-chlorians to support a connection to the Force. A Sith who transferred his essence into a person who was *not* Force sensitive would likely lose his connection to the Force. The lost connection would be permanent, because [a Force-insensitive body cannot be made Force-sensitive](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/49583/31936).

Answer (score 2):

When the Emperor transfers his essence into (various) clone bodies in [Star Wars: Dark Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Empire), it's apparent that his ability to use the force is undiminished.

[image]