# Where do midi-chlorians go after their host dies?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, midichlorians

When a Jedi or a Sith die, do the midi-chlorians somehow emigrate to another person or diffuse out of body and into space?

Could somebody breathe them accidentally and gain a bond with the Force?

Comment: Grievous does not have the lungs of a force sensitive person, they are his original lungs. He received a blood transfusion, and it did not make him force sensitive at all.

Comment: Cropped it to original shape.

Comment: They become midichlorians Force ghosts? Seriously! Do Force Ghosts have midichlorians to sustain them?

Comment: This new version is arguably a dupe of [Are Midi-chlorians able to be infused or transplanted?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/49583/5184). If they can't be infused or transplanted with the result of making someone Force-sensitive, inhaling them probably isn't going to do anything either.

Comment: +1 Good question. I'd also say that someone with enough of them could have his/her consciousness transferred into a Force ghost.

Comment: In the original trilogy, its said that the force is a energy field that is CREATED by all living things. 
So for me the midichlorians are not the force itself but the cells (or something else) that can create the force.

Comment: i'll tell you *where* they can go....

Comment: What made you think that midichlorians are immortals? Also, what about when you die with your body going puff?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Midichlorians are not a separate life-form living freely inside a force-user's body; they're part of a life-form's cells, as much a part of you as your cells' golgi apparatus, cell nuclei, or mitochondria.

The inspiration for the midichlorians was in [fact the mitochondria](https://web.archive.org/web/19991103105353/http://www.eonline.com/News/More/lucas5.html). These are tiny structures inside your cells that help process sugars into energy your cells can use for their metabolic processes. Mitochondria have their own DNA, and relatively recently (late 1980s) it has become widely believed that mitochondria originated as free-living bacteria that were consumed by the early cells that eventually evolved into Eurkaryotes (us), and that mitochondria are therefore symbiotes.

Midichlorians, then, are the organelles in our cells that interact with the Force. They don't create the Force, and they are not synonymous with the Force, but they are the way we perceive and interact with the Force. It's no different from how our eyes use rod and cone cells to interact with electromagnetic radiation, or our hands use skin cells to detect physical interaction. Just because I know that rods and cones are detecting the radiation, that doesn't make a sunset less beautiful.

So, what happens to a person's midichlorians when they die? Their cells die, and the midichlorians in those cells die as well. Same as any other biological structure.

Comment: The midichlorian is the powerhouse of the cell.

Comment: And now I'm upvoting an answer about midichlorians... wonders never cease.

Answer (score 2):

In the original trilogy, it is said that the force is a energy field that is CREATED by all living things.

So for me the midichlorians are not the force itself but the cells (or something else) that can create the force (and therefore allows someone who has a lot of midichlorians to interract with the energy field)

So, in that way, when a person die, all his midichlorians also die and he's not able to create the force or interract wih it.

But IIRC no reference of midichlorians is done in the original trilogy and no reference to how the force works exactly is done in the prelogy... So I can't find something that could bind these both aspects of the force...

PS : I don't think that the ghost are midichlorians living without a body (like RichS said in he's comment), they are souls that have been able to let a mark so strong in the force that their spirit survive in it...