# If some creature was to eat a Jedi or a Sith, would that creature then become Force-sensitive?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, midichlorians

I would like to know if some creature was to eat a Jedi or a Sith, would that mean that the Jedi/Sith's midichlorians would be absorbed into the creature and it would then become Force-sensitive?

Take for instance the Rancor in Jabba the Hutt's palace. If it had managed to eat Luke Skywalker, then that Rancor would have become Force-sensitive, yes?

Moreover, if some creature was to happen to eat a lot of Force-sensitive people, would that creature then become the most powerful Force-sensitive being in the galaxy because its midichlorian count would have increased with each Force-sensitive person that it would have consumed?

[image]

Comment: Essentially the same question here:  https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/e70spl/star_wars_if_you_ate_a_jedi_would_you_absorb_the/

Comment: @Buzz, Okay, well, I guess that answers my question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi there! A question existing in any form (answered or otherwise) is not a reason to delete this question. If anything leaving this question as is will mean it's easier for future users to find the same answer. Also, it means we can properly format and source the answer to be easier to cross reference, which is not as hight a priority on Reddit.

Comment: Wouldn't it dump all the midichlorians again when going to the rancor toilet?

Comment: @Mixxiphoid, good point.

Comment: It depends on how midichlorians get into your system. There's no cannon answer. But in the real world, digestive process only absorb certain things, transforming, destroying or completely ignoring other substances. It's complicated. I think we can assume in this case, and since there is no lore of anyone hunting Jedi to eat them, that no, probably not something to worry about.

Comment: I think no. Eating midichlorians will not cause them to become symbiotic with you. They will either die, being digested, or leave your system in some inert form.

Comment: _Use the Force, Luke... No no, not as an INGREDIENT, good lord..._

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost certainly not, though I am not aware of any instance of a Force-sensitive individual being consumed by a predator and the predator subsequently becoming Force-sensitive or not. However, in canon [blood transfusions do not significantly affect Force sensitivity](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Midi-chlorian#Genetic_experimentation), and that is also the case in Legends (as indicated in [another thread](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/49583/31936)). Consuming a Force-sensitive individual is even less likely to transmit Force sensitivity than a blood transfusion, since the blood of the Force-sensitive individual would be digested rather than enter the predator's bloodstream.

Furthermore, it also seems unlikely just based on what we know about the nature of midi-chlorians and how they allow a Force-sensitive individual to communicate with the Force. We are told the following:

> Midi-chlorians are a microscopic lifeform that reside within all
> living cells and communicates with the Force...Without the
> midi-chlorians, life could not exist, and we would have no knowledge of the
> Force. They continually speak to you, telling you the will of the Force.
>
> <sub>**Qui-Gon Jinn, *Star Wars:* Episode I *The Phantom Menace*** ([source](https://imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-The-Phantom-Menace.html))</sub>

Several points are worth noting about this:

- Midi-chlorians reside within *living* cells, but a Force-sensitive individual's cells (and the midi-chlorians within them) would not survive for long after being eaten by a predator.
- The midi-chlorians are life-forms that *speak* to the Force-sensitive individual, and can choose not to speak to the predator even if they survive.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, at least not if you allow non-canon material. In the [Old Republic](https://www.swtor.com/) game creatures named [Flesh Raiders](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Flesh_Raider) exist on Tython, a world where many Jedi padawans train. The creatures

> had razor-sharp teeth, which they used to strip the bones of both
> sentient and non-sentient prey

At least some of their victims were Force-sensitive. While Force-sensitive Flesh Raiders do exist, they are rare enough that it seems to be unrelated to any consumption of Force users.

Answer (score 1):

**Unlikely**

The digestive tract is an inhospitable place, typically being a highly acidic environment with whose primary function is the breakdown of organic matter into its constituent molecules. It's reasonable to expect that midi-chlorians would be negatively affected by passage through almost any creature's digestive tract to the point that none even survive. One does not simply "absorb" food that they consume and incorporate it wholesale into the body. Instead, the body reduces complex organic matter to relatively few basic common molecules which can be used by the cellular machinery. There's no reason to expect that it would be any different in this case.