# What is the canonicity of Lego Star Wars (TV Episodes)?

Tags: star-wars, canon, lego, lego-star-wars

There was a series of Lego Star Wars episodes that aired on Cartoon Network a few years ago - "The Padawan Menace", "The Empire Strikes Out", and "The Yoda Chronicles".

While these episodes are indeed full of the classic Lego Star Wars humor (Yoda did not likely sit on Mace's lap and say "An awkward, this moment is"), does the larger theme of events have any place in Star Wars canon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The Lego Star Wars series is treated as a ***licensed property*** and as such, totally non-canon.

Although it and the Family Guy specials can be found on the official [Star Wars site,](http://starwars.com/news/lego-star-wars-the-yoda-chronicles-concludes-with-attack-of-the-jedi.html) it is important to stress that the studio does not consider it in any way canonical, indeed there are multiple instances (Yoda meets the droids before ESB, for example) that flatly contradict the events of the films.

Michael Price, senior writer for all six of the recent animated features stated this in an [interview](http://clubjade.net/?p=42609) for Club Jade;

> **Michael:** ***That is actually incredibly freeing — that and the understanding that these LEGO Star Wars shows are most definitely NOT
>   CANON.  So we were free to make up an imaginary back story for Han
>   Solo in The Padawan Menace and, in this show, invent entire events
>   that never took place*** – including the kind of awkward and tense
>   reunion (or, I guess, first ever meeting) of Darth Vader and his
>   “step-brother” Darth Maul.   And the fact that both LEGO and Lucasfilm
>   have been supportive of my narrative sidetracks, the mixing and
>   matching characters and places from the various films, and our
>   satirical swipes at some of the Star Wars sacred cows just has made
>   the whole experience very fun.

Comment: But, is there a LEGO canon, where all the films are internally consistent to themselves?

Comment: @CreationEdge - Not that I'm aware of. There are certainly running jokes but the Lego shows frequently break the fourth wall with Darth turning up in the prequels and speaking to George Lucas, Maul being related to Darth, The Emperor turning up at the start of the Prequels (before he's even become the Emperor), Han meeting Yoda, etc etc. This is a textbook example of "rule of funny". If it's funny, it's in and hang the canon.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that these fall under parody, much like the Family Guy parodies do (Blue Harvest, etc.)

Comment: There is likely a difference in canonicity between a licensed property and a parody.

Comment: Maybe this is an entirely new kind of canon. L-canon.

Comment: @MrLister - Nope, just "non-canon".

Comment: This is not really a full answer without proper references, or sufficient explanation.