# Are deleted scenes considered canon?

Tags: star-wars, canon, revenge-of-the-sith, deleted-scenes

There are a number of deleted scenes (specifically in the prequels) that add a lot of interesting information to the backstory of events and characters in the films.

One that jumps out at me is the meeting in Episode 3 between many of the founders of the Rebel Alliance.

[image: Mon Mothma]

However, there is a scene where Shaak Ti is killed by General Grevious.

[image]

But she appears in the video game, The Force Unleashed. I realize though that the Force Unleashed is considered non-canon as of now but I'm still curious considering that these seem to both be from lower sources of canon and were both created before the Disney buyout.

What is the canonicity and status of these scenes? Obviously they can't be considered G Canon because of times where we have alternate scenes that contradict the locations/characters of actual movie scenes.

Comment: Star Wars is a tangled web of primary canons and secondary canons and semi-canons and partial-canons and used-to-be-canons and particle cannons.  Looking forward to the answers on this one, but methinks they might not be entirely straightforward.

Comment: Wasn't Shaak Ti killed by Order 66? I remember her on Racer and Clones fired from behind.

Comment: The answer to this is no. Only scenes appearing in the current bluray film version are considered true canon. Deleted scenes in the film (and novels) are all 'legends' canon.

Comment: I think, in general, no. Because if that's the case, Jabba the Hutt is simultaneously a giant slug creature, and a fat man in a parka. Canon is complicated and self-contradictory enough with what shows up on screen...

Comment: I realize that none of the deleted scenes are g canon (of the highest degree) but I was curious where they fell into the canon. See this page for what I mean: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Canon#Canon_in_the_Holocron_continuity_database

Comment: Ho! I have my fingers crossed. Hoping Disney has it in their power to restore the Canon timeline. Greedo shot first.

Comment: @David - There's no such thing as G-Canon now.

Comment: So (i'm still trying to wrap my head around everything lol), we have Legends and Canon then correct? Canon being Movies, Clone Wars (cgi), and Rebels? Legends being everything else?

Comment: @David Canon has been greatly simplified; Richard gives a thorough overview in [his answer here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars/80098#80098). You're basically correct; the movies, the two animated shows, and all new material published after April 2014ish is Canon, everything else is Legends. Basically

Comment: The only consistent canons in Star Wars are Laser Cannons

Comment: I'm intrigued as to why this has attracted a reopen vote. Is there any doubt whether this is a dupe?

Comment: @Richard It's not a dupe. The question you linked is asking about overall canon structure 5 years ago. The canon landscape has change immensely since then. This question was related to the canon status of deleted scenes in the new canon.

Comment: @David - Deleted scenes are mentioned specifically in the linked (accepted) answer.

Comment: @David - You may also want to note that although the *question* was asked 5 years ago, my answer to it is fully up to date and has been subject to multiple (ongoing) revisions and input from tens of users in order to keep it that way

Comment: @Richard That's not the point of the question. It wasn't a blanket question about canonicity of deleted scenes which your question covered 5 years ago, but instead about how they fit into the canon with the new Disney Canon.

Comment: @David - You misunderstand. The question may be old, but my answer to it is not. The situation, however, remains the same. Deleted scenes are "legends" canon since they aren't part of the 8 feature films/TV shows. With a few very small exceptions, *everything* that isn't part of the 8 feature films/TV shows is "legends".

Comment: @Richard You may want to edit that answer to make it a bit clearer. I read it as saying that deleted scenes **from Legends material** such as the Holiday Special also counted as Legends material, and thought your answer didn't say anything about deleted scenes from the 7 main films. (I might even have reopened this if not for Null's votes to leave closed.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Better?

Comment: @Richard Definitely - thanks. I'm now comfortable with leaving this question closed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Per my answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars/80098#80098), the simple answer is that canon in the Star Wars *cinematic* universe is currently derived from the [2011 Blu-ray version](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Star-Wars-Complete-Blu-ray-Region/dp/B005HNV2OS) of the Star Wars saga, comprising the 7 feature films as well as the theatrical version of Star Wars VI. Any differences in earlier versions are now considered to have been **fully resolved** by making these the ***definitive*** version with all other versions (including the theatrical cuts of the Original Trilogy and Prequel Trilogy) being now defunct.

Any "deleted scenes" (including those found on the bluray disks) along with any *making-of* documentaries, *behind-the-scenes* documentaries, concept art books and previous versions of the scripts (along with scenes in the Official Novelisations that aren't directly based on what's seen in these Blu-rays) are considered to be "*Legends*" within the Star Wars universe.

Until <s>Lucas</s> Disney change it again, obviously.

[image]

Comment: So we're forever saddled with the Darth Vader "NO!" scream in RotJ? This is a sad day indeed.

Comment: @david - and Jar Jar ( * sigh * )

Comment: I wouldn't have minded if Disney just said "Hey we're going to remake the Prequels." Its not like they could get much worse.

Comment: @david - Or just completely de-canonised them.

Comment: @David Hey, if they can re-tell the origin story of Spider-man cinematically 3 times over, why not?