# Can Greedo regenerate?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, greedo

Is it possible that George Lucas's original intent when creating *Star Wars* (*Ep. IV A New Hope*) was that Greedo was of a race that can regenerate fairly quickly?  Is it possible that Han-shot-first because he knew it wouldn't kill Greedo, only stun him?

I'm asking because of this shot *(appearing at 51:40 in Harmy's Despecialized Edition; so should match timing in VHS/LaserDisc versions)*:

[image: Greedo-lookalike after getting shot walking through the corridor; 51:40 in Star Wars (Harmy's Despecialized Edition)]

This occurs 1 minute 38 seconds after Han shoots Greedo (film-time); given the events that occur, I'd estimate that 30-60 minutes have passed since Han shooting and the “Greedo-lookalike” roaming around the corridors of Mos Eisley.  Is it possible that Greedo was just knocked-out while his mid-body organs (and clothes, apparently) regenerated?  Or is it more feasible that others of Greedo's race (Rodian) were present in Mos Eisley, *and wearing the same outfit?!*

The later-Rodian looks to be wearing almost the same outfit as Greedo (though it might be a brown coarse-cotton vest with a pocket instead of the more silkly vest Greedo's seen wearing).

*For comparison, 49:57 in the same version:*

[image: Greedo sat across from the table to Han with the subtitles reading "I've been looking forward to this for a long time"; 49:57 in Star Wars (Harmy's Despecialized Edition)]

“It could've been a filming/editing continuity error” is not an acceptable answer because… no kidding.  George slipped many other subtle details into ANH though, so I'm looking for something more real.

Comment: I don't understand why this is being downvoted - it's an interesting question about something I've never noticed in one of the most influential and popular films of all time.

Comment: @DrRDizzle It was probably downvoted for digging up Han's dead horse. Me, I was almost tempted to not upvote for that reason. Anyway, the novelization has Jabba say Greedo was "fried".

Comment: @MrLister Peh.  There's a reason why Lucas filmed & edited this movie the way he did in ~1977.  Rewatching these again, that's what I'm interested in.  The ___-shot-first argument happened 20 years later— I don't care.  I'm less digging it up, and more acknowledging only that it died.

Comment: @MrLister The reason for the question may be a little off-putting, but the question itself is effectively "Did Greedo survive his encounter with Han, here is some evidence that he might have, and if he did, how?". I think that's an interesting question.

Comment: I think the major problem with this question is the framing. It would have been far better to go with something like "*If greedo got shot in the bar, then who the heck is this guy?*"

Comment: @Richard Maybe.  I'm currently convinced that Jar Jar is Sidious's master and R2 is a jedi more powerful (and sly!) than Anakin ever was, so I'm in a what-if mindset.  My question holds because that's the proposition that interests me; if it crashes & burns, feel free to post a more open-ended variant.

Comment: Like @Richard says, it's the framing definitely. "Did Greedo survive the encounter with Han" is a far better wording. "Does he have regenerative powers / can he regrow his organs?" is plain silly! Why did you lock in this line of thought? Maybe he was a robot. Maybe he was an hologram. Maybe Han was having a drug-induced dream. All equally plausible explanations.

Comment: Maybe he's a Timelord?

Comment: It could be Greedo's identical twin brother, Charito. Or maybe Ol' George missed a trick. He could have had Han shoot first, but knowing Greedo would survive it, making Han not such a bad guy after all.

Comment: This is so Rodian racist I can't even.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Ha!  Unfortunately, discrimination between 99.999%-same-genetics human races and likely 0.1%-same-genetics alien species isn't quite the same ballpark.  It's like putting international football and american football players on the same field, and then complaining that one team has an unfair advantage— no kidding, one team can tackle and pick up the ball.

Comment: @AndresF. I went with that line of reasoning because it's Star Wars-y.  The other possibilities you've brought up are rare events in Star Wars, and usually worthy of their own plots in movies or their own books/cartoons/games (stories are told about exceptional events, not just the everyday norm).  An intelligent creature who can regenerate like an IRL salamander isn't unusual or extraordinary in the Star Wars universe, AFAIK— many of the Star Wars creatures' designs have IRL aquatic/amphibian creature inspirations.  That said, it's not like another explanation would be down-voted.

Comment: "George slipped many other subtle details into ANH though". s/slipped into/retconned/g. A budget space flick from the 70s is not Kubrick.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Many Bothans have died to bring me the information that this Rodian is called [**Thuku**](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Thuku)

[image: Thuku trading card showing a close up of the character at Mos Eisley from the same scene in the question]

For the record, Jabba has at least a half-dozen Rodians in his employ, all of whom seem to dress *similarly*, but not *identically*.

[image: Jabba and his men confront Han at the Falcon in Mos Eisley, 3 Rodians are circled in the background]

---

Per Pablo Hidalgo in [Star Wars Insider #63](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_63)

> **Q. How come in Episode IV, after Han fries Greedo, you see him walking around Mos Eisley and at Han’s ship?**
>
> **PH:** Those other Rodians aren't Greedo, but clearly Rodians aren’t that creative or individualistic when it comes to wardrobe. Costume production notes indicate that there were three Rodians in the cantina all dressed the same. Tales from the Mos Eisley Cantina establishes that one of them was named Thuku. Also, watch the Jabba scene at Han’s ship carefully. There are at least three Rodians dressed identically. Furthermore, in Return of the Jedi, we see another Rodian with the same duds, only this guy's named Beedo.

Comment: +1 For the many-Rodians bit.  I assume those aren't SE-only, just from that deleted scene.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson - That scene doesn't appear in the original edit (at all) so yes, obviously this is from a later version. They do appear in the [original cut of that scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Sf4eb9l__4) though, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: It was filmed in ~1976.  AFAIK, only CG Jabba was added in the 90s.  Sorry, that's what I meant.  Filmed-in-70s-deleted vs. CG-created-in-90s, the former preferred.

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson Since it is in the 2011 Blu-Ray release, this scene is canon. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/86521/1973

Comment: -1 for killing bothans. What are you, [Ishori](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ishori) ?

Comment: @SlippD.Thompson - Boba Fett was also added to this scene in the 90s, FYI.

Comment: Rodians are apparently the clone army of the Hutt clan.

Comment: Which makes sense. In Jedi Outcast, Rodians are the guys who snipe using disruptor rifles which can vapourise you. Can you imagine an army of genetically enhanced clones of the greatest Rodian sniper in the Hurt Clans' employ?

Comment: "Many Bothans have died" — chopped up and made into trading cards? Dark!

Answer (score 5):

The guy on the background of the first picture does not necessarily need to be Greedo.

He is of course of the same race and wearing a similar outfit, but have a look at these guys:

[image: Imperial officers line a hangar bay on the Death Star all wearing the same outfit and looking similar]

or even these:

[image: 3 rebel pilots, including Luke, in their distinctive orange uniforms are stood talking together]

They all look the same (at least, I suppose that from the point of view of a Rodian, all Humans should look the same), and they all are dressed, more or less, in the same way.

---

Probably the simplest explanation is that the brown/green suit is some sort of uniform and the green alien in the background is not Greedo but another Rodian.

Comment: True, but that first image is from a public area in a city that has a wide variety of creatures from a wide variety of places— _not a military base, which you've pictured_.  Your point is valid and covered by @Valorum's answer, but I don't find the validation of your point to be substantial.  On earth in real life, when was the last time you visited a public plaza and saw multiple civilians who looked roughly the same wearing the same outfit (excluding special events)?  Valorum's answer provides the proof that these were private soldiers in service of Jabba.