# What happens to Jedi expelled from the order?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, attack-of-the-clones

In this scene from *Star Wars: Attack of the Clones*, Obiwan tells Anakin that he would be expelled from the Jedi Order if he puts his personal feelings ahead of his duties.

> Padme falls from ship after it is hit by lasers.
>
> Anakin: Padme! (to pilot:) Put the ship down.
>
> Obiwan: Anakin, don't let your personal feelings get in the way. (to pilot:) Follow that speeder.
>
> Anakin: Lower the ship.
>
> Obiwan: I can't take Dooku alone. I need you. If we catch him, we can end this war right now. We have a job to do.
>
> Anakin: I don't care. (to pilot:) Put the ship down.
>
> Obiwan: **You will be expelled from the Jedi Order.**

Clearly there are some transgressions so great that the Jedi Council will expel somebody from the order. **What happens to expelled Jedi?**

Are they left alone to do as they please? That seems unlikely since as powerful Force-users, they can become very dangerous.

Are they killed? That seems contrary to Jedi values.

If the transgression was a crime, are they turned over to law enforcement? I doubt many law enforcers could arrest and hold a Jedi.

Does it depend on how powerful the Jedi is?

Does it depend on how bad their transgression?

I am not asking about [the twenty Jedi who did not commit any transgressions, but voluntarily left the Order](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116608/only-20-jedi-left-the-order), such as Count Dooku. I am asking about those left involuntarily.

Nor am I asking about [the fate of any surviving Jedi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129187/what-was-the-fate-of-the-disbanded-former-jedi-order-members-after-order-66-exec) after the Order was destroyed by the Sith.

I have only seen the movies, so if this is answered in other canon sources, just provide answers from those sources.

Comment: Didn't this exact thing happen to Ahsoka Tano when she was framed? Resulting in her snubbing the whole stuck-up holier-than-thou order after her exoneration.

Comment: Speaking of Ahsoka Tano, Barriss Offee was marked a traitor, and arrested for her crimes.

Comment: Was Dooku expelled, or did he just leave?  And would the Jedi Order essentially treat someone who left as if they had been expelled?

Comment: Well I added an answer from legends, if you don't have anything against such an answer we should add the legends tag

Answer (score 23):

In the Clone Wars TV series (canon) we have

> [Ashoka Tano](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Ahsoka_Tano). She was framed for bombing the Jedi temple on Coruscant. She was removed from the Jedi Order and facing execution. While she would eventually be exonerated, she grew to mistrust the Jedi council and did not return to the Jedi order after being pardoned. Tano did wind up helping the Jedi, however, right up until Palpatine gave Order 66, which forced Tano into hiding.

*Are they killed? That seems contrary to Jedi values.*

They would execute some criminals after a trial and conviction by the Jedi themselves (murder and sedition seem to be two good reasons). We don't know what happened to Jedi accused of merely committing petty crimes, abusing power, etc.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if it's ever addressed in Disney's official canon, but I do have an answer from Star Wars Legends.

In *Star Wars Knights of the Old Republic II: The Sith Lords* the main character ('canonically' named Meetra Surik) was expelled from the Jedi Order, and is thus commonly known as 'the Exile.' The Jedi Council took away their lightsaber and then they walked away free. So it seems that under Legends, all that happens is losing your lightsaber and recognition as a member of their order. The game refers to special cases where the Jedi have cut someone off from the Force but didn't do it to the Exile, so it at least wasn't always done to those expelled from the Order, but it's possible it was done sometimes.

Comment: What's to stop someone who has been expelled from just creating a new lightsaber?

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Nothing. It can be done in the game.

Comment: Knights of the Old Republic II: The Sith Lords is set 4000 years before The Phantom Menace. Practices then may be very different from practices in the Skywalker saga

Comment: @SpacePhoenix I imagine it's like what happens when a cop is kicked off the force and has to turn in his badge and gun.  Nothing stops him from simply buying another gun...