# How much of Star Wars movie deleted scenes are canon?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, deleted-scenes

If the answer is not a unanimous yes/no, please identify the particular scenes which are considered canon based on what we currently know. Please state so too if the answer differs between Legends and current canon - I am looking for answers covering both canonicities.

Comment: Deleted scenes are non-canon ("*Legends*"). Canonicity for the Star Wars films is determined by a scene's inclusion **in the 2011 Bluray edition**.

Comment: This question is also a direct dupe of [Are (Star Wars) deleted scenes considered canon?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86485/are-deleted-scenes-considered-canon?rq=1) which I answered in a bit more detail before it was closed.