# Are 'The Lost Missions' part of the official Star Wars canon?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

The new Disney canon includes *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* TV series, but are *The Lost Missions* (e.g. the unfinished season 6 of *Star Wars: The Clone Wars*) considered a full part of the Star Wars canon?

Comment: It's a bit recursive, but I've linked my answer here into the  dupe question since it adds a little bit of extra info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see absolutely no reason to think that they aren't 100% canonical. They were written and produced by the cast and crew of the other 'Star Wars : The Clone Wars' episodes, received an official release (on DVD, online and on TV) and each episode has a [title listing](http://www.starwars.com/tv-shows/clone-wars/the-unknown#!/about) on the starwars.com website.

> **Exclusive Licensing Agreement with The Disney/ABC Television Group
>   Brings Star Wars Content to Netflix Streaming Members for the First
>   Time**
>
> The Galactic Republic, Disney/ABC Television Group, Lucasfilm, and
>   Netflix Inc. today announced the highly anticipated debut of the sixth
>   and final season of the Emmy(r) Award-winning series Star Wars: The
>   Clone Wars exclusively to Netflix members in the US and Canada on
>   Friday, March 7. Accompanying the 13-episode new season dubbed “The
>   Lost Missions” will be the entire Star Wars: The Clone Wars saga,
>   which includes several director’s cut episodes never seen on TV as
>   well as the feature film. This multi-year agreement also makes Netflix
>   the exclusive subscription service for the entire Star Wars: The Clone
>   Wars series.

These episodes (along with the comic series [Sons of Dathomir](https://www.facebook.com/DaveFiloni/posts/10152103755565053)) are considered to be a full part of the Star Wars/Disney canon.