# Has any Jedi regularly used two or more lightsabers in Disney Canon?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, lightsaber

It's not uncommon for us to see a Sith using two or more lightsabers.  We also see that General Grievous uses four lightsabers.  So, my question is **do we ever see a Jedi *in Disney Canon* who uses more than one lightsaber *on a regular occasion*?**  I don't mean uses two lightsabers once or twice, but *normally* combats using two or more lightsabers.

Comment: In a Battlefront videogame, **Aayla Secura** wielded two lightsabers, but I don't remember if there is a more canonical confirmation of this.

Comment: @Ifurini I think [it is canon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_canon)

Comment: Probably because you mentioned General Grievous and Sith in the same sentence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a couple, though few who use the technique regularly:

- [Ahsoka Tano](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ahsoka_Tano/Canon) used two lightsabers in all of her appearances in *The Clone Wars* (the CG-animated one, which is [fully-canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910)) from season 3 onwards

  [image]

  She's also been seen with two lightsabers in *Star Wars Rebels*:

  [image]
- It may not be exactly what you're looking for, but Master [Pong Krell](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Pong_Krell/Canon) wielded two (double-bladed) lightsabers in his appearances in *The Clone Wars*:

  [image]

  Although Krell only appeared in one (four episode) story arc of the show, nothing about his appearance suggested that this was an uncommon occurrence; he didn't borrow one from another Jedi, or steal one from a Dark Jedi or Sith. It seems reasonable to assume that this is normal battle practice for him.

The list of Jedi who have *occasionally* used multiple lightsabers in combat is rather longer, though not by a whole lot:

- Anakin Skywalker used his and Obi-Wan's lightsabers during his duel with Count Dooku in the climax of *Attack of the Clones*, and briefly used Dooku's lightsaber in their duel early in *Revenge of the Sith*
- [Kit Fisto](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kit_Fisto) used his slain padawan's lightsaber in a duel with General Grevious in the first-season *The Clone Wars* episode "[Lair of Greivous](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lair_of_Grievous)"
- Obi-Wan Kenobi borrows Adi Gallia's lightsaber to battle Maul and Savage Oppress in "[Revival](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Revival_(episode))", a fifth-season episode of *The Clone Wars*
- Though arguably not a Jedi at this point, [Barriss Offee](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Barriss_Offee/Canon) used two lightsabers stolen from the Dark Jedi Asajj Ventress during the final arc of *The Clone Wars* season 5
- Kanan Jarrus borrowed Ezra Bridger's lightsaber during a duel against a Sith Inquisitor in the season 1 finale of *Star Wars Rebels*

Comment: Great answer!  Here - have a +1

Comment: @N_Soong You're thinking of the cell-shaded *Clone Wars* show; the CG *The Clone Wars* is [fully canon](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars/80098#80098)

Comment: I had been operating under the impression that *The Clone Wars* CG was Legends; thanks for clarifying that!

Comment: I will also add to this answer, that the Jedi guards in the Temple in the same cartoon have been seen wielding double-bladed sabers like Maul's.

Comment: @thegreatjedi I wouldn't classify that as "two lightsabers," but I'll let the OP make that judgement

Comment: @thegreatjedi I would accept the instances in the above answer as being 'two or more lightsabers', but I wouldn't consider a dual lightsaber like Darth Maul's as two independent lightsabers