# Does Han Solo have twins?

Tags: star-wars

The real fans of Star Wars are talking about Han Solo having twins, a boy and a girl. Is there a canon answer to that?

Comment: İ changed the question with this one after that comment

Comment: @JasonBaker Indeed; close-vote retracted (and upvote added) after that very major edit! And I'll delete my above comments to avoid spoilers ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by "the real fans of Star Wars"?

Comment: @icey Please don't completely change questions like that in the future.  Delete it and post your new question separately next time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably hearing mention of [Jacen](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Caedus) and [Jaina](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jaina_Solo_Fel) Solo, introduced in Timothy Zahn's *Thrawn* trilogy (Leia was pregnant through the first two books, and the twins were born in the last).

The Solo twins were regular character in the *Star Wars* Expanded Universe novels, and are quite popular among many fans of the EU, but are [no longer canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars); they were relegated to the non-canon Legends continuity with the rest of the EU following Disney's takeover of Lucasfilm.

In the current canon, Han and Leia only have one known child, revealed in *The Force Awakens*:

> Kylo Ren, whose birth name is Ben

Whether Disney will borrow any elements from Jacen and Jaina's adventures remains to be seen; there's already at least one similarity:

> In the *Legacy of the Force* novels, published between 2006 and 2008, Jacen Solo fell to the Dark Side and became Darth Caedus. One of his more unsettling acts was killing his younger brother, Anakin Solo.

The similarities to *The Force Awakens* should be obvious.

Comment: IIRC, Jacen was also front-and-center in one of the Jedi Academy games.

Comment: @Derek Are you thinking of [Jaden Korr](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jaden_Korr), the playable character from Jedi Academy?

Comment: ah, yea that's it.

Comment: Actually, we don't know that Ben is Solo (vs. Organa)

Comment: @DVK Rolled back

Comment: We don't know that Ben is their only child...

Comment: @Axelrod Edited