# Has Han met a Wookiee aside from Chewbacca?

Tags: star-wars

In *Star Wars: A New Hope*, Han famously makes a comment about Wookiees ripping people's arms off. This got me to thinking whether this was a reasonable generalisation. **Has Han Solo ever met another Wookiee aside from Chewbacca?** Canon preferred but Legends is acceptable,

Comment: I'll just leave [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_mmWCuYS0o) here and walk away slowly

Comment: @Richard an under appreciated masterpiece 

Comment: I quite like it.

Comment: @YperSillyCubeᵀᴹ good point, although it doesn't really impact the question!

Comment: Important to remember: Lucas originally intended Han to have grown up with Wookiees. Mention of it just never made the final scripts.

Comment: @Richard - flagged as offensive. On second thought, that requires its own new kind of flag.

Comment: @DVK - VTC reason = "**This post contains references to the Star Wars: Holiday Special**".

Comment: @Richard This request needs to get fast tracked through Meta immediately. Somebody think of the children!

Comment: As a smuggler traveling throughout the galaxy it seems safe to assume Han met many individuals of all major sentient races.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Yes, but after *A New Hope*

In the recent marvel comic six issue crossover event, *Darth Vader Down*, Han and Chewie encounter [**Black Krrsantan**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Krrsantan), a Wookiee warrior.

[image]

While this comic is considered canon, it takes place after *A New Hope*, so it won't help explain Han's comment.

Answer (score 34):

In the [Star Wars Holiday Special](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Star_Wars_Holiday_Special) Han Solo meets several members of Chewbacca's family, and actually participates in a large Wookiee ceremony with dozens if not hundreds of other Wookiees.

While this takes place after a New Hope, Solo is very familiar with the planet suggesting he'd been there before. Additionally, since this is Chewbacca's family, it seems reasonable that Solo had met them early in his relationship with Chewy.

I'm not sure if the Holiday Special counts as canon, but it certainly has all the original actors. Now, whether or not you want to scar yourself by watching it is another matter.

[YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z_mmWCuYS0o) (courtesy of Richard).

Comment: Holiday Special isn't canon at all, just to be clear. Not even EU/Legends, thank the Maker!

Comment: I almost want to downvote you just for mentioning that... thing

Comment: Its kind of the opposite of canon. Its something we've all agreed never happened by near universal consent. * waves hand * There was no holiday special. * waves hand * You can move along.

Comment: Chewie's wife [Malla](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Malla) is mentioned in the Disney canon novel [*A New Hope: The Princess, the Scoundrel, and the Farm Boy*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/A_New_Hope:_The_Princess,_the_Scoundrel,_and_the_Farm_Boy), so she is now re-canonized. Although the reference to her doesn't indicate whether or not Han actually met her or just knew about her.

Comment: It may not be canon, but it should be the target of cannon.  Many cannon.

Comment: Note that even if it was canon, it too takes place after A New Hope, so can't explain the comment either, unless Han has met Chewbacca's family before.

Comment: @MiloPrice while that is true, solo is very familiar with the planet, suggesting he'd been there before.

Comment: Also, for the record, I started writing this post before I saw Richard's comment. I didn't just blantantly steal his idea :)

Answer (score 27):

Since ibid covered Disney canon, let’s cover EU/Legends for completeness.

The origin of “Ripping people’s arms off” meme, retconned in-universe, is Han Solo’s friend/caregiver/surrogate mother, Wookiee [Dewlanna (full name Dewlannamapia)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dewlannamapia).

His relationship with her while being a juvenile criminal on Shrike’s crew is described in Han Solo trilogy by Crispen (especially, *Paradise Snare*).

In the book, while helping Han escape Trader’s Luck, she broke Larrad Shrike’s arm easily, but in that fight was mortally wounded, which cemented his warm feelings towards Wookiees and ensured he would be set upon his path when he met Chewbacca as an Imperial slave.

> His words had no more effect than Han’s. Dewlanna’s blood was up—she was in full Wookiee battle rage. With a roar that deafened the combatants, **she grabbed Larrad’s wrist and yanked, spinning him around and snapping him in a terrible parody of a child’s “snap the whip” game. Han heard a crunch, mixed with several pops as tendons and ligaments gave way**. Larrad Shrike shrieked, a high, shrill noise that carried such pain that the Corellian youth’s arm ached in sympathy.

Comment: From the same source - he encountered Wookies via the Imperial academy where they were valued as slaves for their strength. (And is why he hooked up with Chewbacca).

Comment: And, in the same book series, they actually make a trip to Kashyyyk to meet with the resistance.

Comment: It's really a shame that the Han Solo Omnibus is not considered canon. It's really a good story and well told. A. C. Crispen did a fantastic job on that trilogy.

Comment: @mawcsco - amen. Crispen is probably my top 3 EU author (Zahn is unquestionably #1); and I deeply wish they used her and Zahn instead of the ... extremely underwhelming hirelings... Disney used for new canon.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with your Zahn and Crispen assessment.

Answer (score 4):

### Yes:

As [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/113250/44025) explains, in the novel *Star Wars - Journey to The Force Awakens:  Aftermath* by Chuck Wendig<sup>1</sup>, Han and Chewie travel to the Wookiee homeworld of Kashyyyk and liberate it from Imperial control.  It is all but impossible to imagine anyone going to a Wookiee planet and failing to meet at least a few Wookiees.  Furthermore, Han specifically mentions that they should contact a group of a half dozen Wookiee refugees, including Roshyk, Hrrgn, and Kirratha. It's pretty clear that he and Chewbacca already know these six Wookiees, at the very least.

> "We've got an opportunity with a very small window."
>
> Chewie gurgles and Han agrees: "Imra, like you said: I'm out of that life, so whatever it is you're bringing to me-"
>
> She disappears and a new holo-image pops up: a planet...
>
> **It's Kashyyyk.**
>
> **It's Chewie's home.**
>
> **A planet where Wookiees are still in thrall to the Empire...**
>
> "They're gonna do... who can say? A changing of the guards or something. Or they need ships for some planet or some other - I really don't know, Solo. The details are fuzzy, but what we do know is, the ships that are leaving won't immediately be replaced. Which means we have a few days."
>
> "When?"
>
> "Now."
>
> Chewie raises his head back and howls...
>
> "The Alliance - the New Republic, whatever they are - they got me on this thing. I've got a responsibility. I can't just change the plan and go off half-cocked...." And he knows what the New Republic will say. They have a strategy. They won't divert attention to Kashyyyk, not yet. He's asked. More than once.
>
> Chewie is giving him this look. Not even making a sound. The Wookiee's chest is rising and falling.
>
> And it hits Han: The words coming out of his mouth don't sound like him. Being out here, though, with Chewie, it's made him feel like he used to. They'd just go places. Do whatever they wanted. Follow their noses to drink and contraband and stacks of credits and whatever good or bad deeds came along.
>
> A fire lights in Han's belly.
>
> It's time to do this...
>
> "Get everybody. Every right-thinking scamp, scoundrel, slicer, smuggler - anybody who owes me a favor. Anybody who hates the Empire like we do."
>
> He turns to Chewbacca: “**Hey, pal. You still know how to contact the other refugees? Roshyk, Hrrgn, Kirratha, and them?” Group of a half-dozen Wookiees who escaped Kessel and got away from the Empire when nobody else could. Group of the meanest, hairiest brutes. They’re mercenaries now, and they don’t have much care in them when it comes to the politics of the New Republic, but they damn sure will care about liberating their home.**
>
> Chewie nods and growls in assent.
>
> "**Good. Get ’em together. And, Imra, you get the rest. Tell them to meet us outside Warrin Station. Like, now. Hell, yesterday**. We don’t need the Alliance or the Republic. We do this our way.”
>
> The Wookiee pumps his long arms in triumph. Imra gives her word, and then she’s gone.
>
> “We don’t have any plan, pal,” he says. The Wookiee growls.
>
> “We’re making this up as we go.” Chewie nods and ululates.
>   - *Star Wars - Journey to the Force Awakens: Aftermath*

---

<sup>1</sup>*Poorly written - **very** poorly written - but canonical nonetheless, this story takes place in the months following the Battle of Endor, the destruction of the second Death Star, and the death of Vader and Palpatine*