# Has there ever been talks of making a movie based on The Old Republic?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, star-wars-the-old-republic

Does anyone know if there have ever been plans to make make movies set in the era of KotOR. A movie based around the Sith in that time could prove to be very interesting, as would any movie based on games set in the era of the KotOR

Comment: I highly doubt it, as those events are all Legends (i.e. non-canon).

Comment: @Null Have they always been non-canon? Or is that just since the Disney purchase? If they've never been, do you know if there is any canon material based on the timeline for that era?

Comment: @H.Buckton http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars

Comment: @H.Buckton - The KOTOR stuff has always been non-canon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I'm sure there have been extensive *discussions*, the latest information is that there have been no formal talks regarding the production of a KOTOR film or a film set in the distant past of the Star Wars universe.

There *were* some unsubstantiated rumours in 2013 about Drew Karpyshyn writing a screenplay for LucasFilm but this was [point-blank denied by him](https://twitter.com/DrewKarpyshyn/status/305385159002316800) and since then, the KOTOR books, game and other properties have been [declared by Disney to be remaining non-canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars), making a film even less likely.

Comment: Thank you very much. I find it relatively annoying for Disney to declare great works as non-canon, especially pieces set that far in the past, considering they don't seem to be showing an interest in any of the timeline before the original saga.

Comment: @H.Buckton KOTOR was never really canon. Disney didn't declare it non-canon.

Comment: @H.Buckton - Can't really blame Disney for this one. The KOTOR games and books were always non-canon, Disney just confirmed that they were staying that way.

Comment: @Richard Apologies, I misinterpreted what was said. Thanks for the edit for clarification.

Comment: Amusing how KotOR and a lot of other legends non-canon is monumentally better story telling than 1-3, 1-6(haven't seen 7 yet) the cartoons and other canon.

Comment: @Minativ7 Having writers whose jobs depend on their audience liking what they write helps.  Lucas doesn't give a -- that you prefer Han shooting first, and JJ would have continued rolling in his filthy spoils had 7 been bad.

Comment: @Richard *Everything* was canon until Disney came in. KOTOR and KOTOR2 had a set of canon decisions (and even face choices). Disney recently included Rakata Prime in the Visual Dictionary, so there's hope that maybe they'll realize the *Game of the Year, groundbreaking series* could make them some cash.

Comment: @Richard That's Disney rules. Pre-Disney, all official works were canon.