# Do Force users ever manipulate lava?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

I'm not well versed in the books, comics etc. surrounding the Star Wars universe, are there any examples where a Force user has manipulated lava? I'm thinking along the line of throwing lumps of lava at others or creating "snakes" of lava to use as a weapon. I suppose this could depend on whether they've manipulated other liquids too, however in this case I'm primarily interested in lava.

Comment: Most of the books are labeled Star Wars Legends. Do you wish to include Legends or restrict answerers to canon?

Comment: I cannot recall any canon examples from any of the Star Wars books I have read, however, if Anakin Skywalker had known about such a power everything that occurred after Episode II may have led to a completely different Star Wars universe.

Comment: The force can be used to move and interact with objects in general, there's very few if any canon material that shows them actually manipulating elemental forces like fire or lava.

Comment: Lava Release - Rasenshuriken! Not going to happen, but would be immeasurably epic.

Comment: I thought my answer (with the addition of the storyboards) was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything else you'd want me to address before considering an acceptance?

Comment: I'll be honest, I hadn't seen the update with the storyboards. That seems to be the closest thing to what I had in mind, which is a shame as it only got as far as a storyboard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In (Legends canon) novel [Star Wars: Jedi Search](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jedi_Search) Luke fights a fireworm ([no, really](https://media.giphy.com/media/3rgXBLKe3lGpCR6Kje/giphy.gif)).

At the end of the fight it explodes, sending gobbets of lava into the air. Luke moves the larger "*chunks*" using the Force.

> *Gouts of acrid smoke poured from the chink in the silicon armor, where
>   lava ate its way into the fireworm’s body core. The creature writhed
>   and tossed, spewing lava into the air. Molten rock devoured the
>   fireworm’s internal organs like acid, killing it from the inside out.*
>
> *Burning within, the fireworm thrashed in agony, spraying lava as
>   flames and foul smoke boiled out of the tiny breach in its armor. When
>   the fiery rock burned through to the fireworm’s inflated air bladders,
>   the creature exploded.*
>
> ***Splatters of hardening lava rained down. Luke managed to deflect most
>   of the burning chunks with the Force,*** but some scorched his back and
>   shoulder. The fireworm’s death throes churned waves in the molten
>   rock, then gradually subsided.

And in these storyboarded (but not filmed) scenes from Revenge of the Sith, we see Anakin using the Force to hurl lava a couple of times, once against a shield (to minimal effect) and again during the climax of his duel with Kenobi

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that manipulating the lava itself? It seems more like using the force to move objects.

Comment: @DoctorWho22 - It's lava, he's moving it.

Comment: I would hesitate to call it lava manipulation though, it's just telekinesis. Force Sensitives can use the force to move things in general.

Comment: Also technically speaking Legends isn't canon.  All of the Expanded Universe was placed under the name Star Wars Legends by Lucasfilms in 2014.

Comment: I strongly suspect that the person who posted this answer is [quite well aware of how canonicity is determined in Star Wars](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars/80098#80098)

Comment: Well I think that any force user's ability to "manipulate" lava is essentially just using telekinesis.  Considering that lava is just molten rocks and the example shows them moving hardening lava / burning chunks they are just moving it with that power.  Psycrow wanted lava manipulation, part of the question was also asking about being able to create lava snakes which you have never seen this level of manipulation of an element other than force lightning by the Sith.  And it seemed that somebody changed it to include "Legends canon".

Comment: @DoctorWho22 - Although the OP was clearly wanting to know whether any Jedi are also [lavabenders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0UpCffFxkeI), they left the question open by asking about "***throwing lumps of lava***"

Comment: @Valorum Actually they also asked if Jedi manipulated liquids too, which in turn makes me believe they were asking moreso about lavabending than just moving it in general.

Comment: @DoctorWho22 - That's why you need to phrase your questions carefully. To stop clever buggers like me finding 'edge cases' that meet the requirements without necessarily fitting what the OP intended ;-)

Comment: The thing is you only answered one aspect of the original question without addressing the rest, so you only really met one part of the requirement for the question. Or that's how I see it, like I said earlier considering that they were wondering about moving chunks, creating animate objects using lava as a weapon, and being able to manipulate other things including liquids.

Comment: @DoctorWho22 - [Partial answers](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) need love too...

Comment: To me partial answers are not good answers, a good answer is in depth and attacks all points of a question instead of just answering one.  But if people want to upvote a partial answer that's on them.

Comment: @DoctorWho22 - Per the FAQ: "*Help us find a solution by researching the problem, then contribute the results of your research and anything additional you’ve tried as a partial answer. That way, even if we can’t figure it out, the next person has more to go on.*"

Comment: And as it says it's so that the next person has more to go on, which to me indicates that the next person looking up or researching information will end up having a more complete answer.

Comment: @DoctorWho22 "Is that manipulating the lava itself? It seems more like using the force to move objects." Lava is an object. The Force moves objects. Therefore, the force can move lava. I really don't understand your problem with this answer.

Comment: There's a difference between actually just moving an object than making it turn into an animate object.

Comment: The person who asked the question wanted to know can they make "snakes" of lava as a sort of weapon.  Just regular lifting, throwing, stopping of lava is not the same as manipulating it in a way that it creates animate objects.  A good example of a similar type of thing is most types of bending in Avatar.  Earthbenders are able to do things like turning surfaces into quicksand, which is way different than just moving an object.

Comment: There's various different powers in general that deal with elements such as Geokinesis or "Earth Manipulation" http://powerlisting.wikia.com/wiki/Earth_Manipulation

Oh and another form of geokinesis that Avatar uses is an Earthbender being able to magnetize their own limbs.

Answer (score 2):

Overall Force Sensitives have the power of [telekinesis](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Telekinesis) which allows them to move solid matter as well as other substances.

> Telekinesis was the ability to lift or manipulate objects using the
>   power of the Force. For a sufficiently skilled practitioner, the size
>   of the object did not matter. One could lift something as small as a
>   piece of fruit to an X-wing starfighter, as well as dispel gaseous
>   substances.
>
> Source: *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* – "The Zillo Beast Strikes Back"

An example is Anakin lifting a mundane item like an apple.

[image: Anakin Force lifting an apple]

In the newer movie they show Kylo stopping a blaster mid shot as well, so they stop energy blasts too using telekenises.

> Kylo Ren was skilled in telekinesis, able to suspend a blaster bolt in
>   midair and leave it harmlessly hanging until he left the scene.
>
> *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*

Telekinesis seems to only be able to lift, move, stop, or deflect objects though Wookieepedia claims manipulation of most objects.  You wanted to know if it was possible to throw lumps of lava at people or create lava snakes.  The former of throwing lumps of lava is possible through telekinesis but creating snakes of lava I think would not fall under telekinesis as it's much more than just moving an object.

As far as reference material I'm unsure if the following is considered canon material... But there are instances of Force Sensitives that "manipulate elements", mainly Sith though.

There are a few force sensitives that can actually manipulate elements.  One such group  was the Sith known as [Shapers of Kro Var](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Shapers_of_Kro_Var).

> The Shapers of Kro Var wielded the dark side of the Force,[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JA8sp.jpg) and were
>   regarded as being deeply connected to the elements of earth, fire,
>   air, and water. Their abilities included buckling stone, creating
>   walls of wind, and generating spouts of flame. They could ignite
>   targets using fire, or make their motion more fluid in battle. Their
>   manifestations of the Force depended on their element of study, but
>   were also influenced by the location of their habitat. Shapers native
>   to the Ungoth Valley were more apt at wielding fire due to the
>   presence of lava flows there.
>
> Sources: *Jedi Academy Training Manual* by Wizards of the Coast
>
> *Book of Sith: Secrets from the Dark Side.*

The manual is considered to be reliable information as far as expanded universe material [according to Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Wookieepedia:Canon_policy).

On a side note Sith can use force lightning which is essentially discharging electricity from their fingertips.

[image: Force Lightning]

Over all it seems what you are asking is more akin to the type of manipulation seen in the Avatar The Last Airbender / Korra universe, some Earthbenders have been seen manipulating lava as well as a few firebenders.