# Is there any example of gene therapy in the Star Wars canon?

Tags: star-wars, science

I tried researching it, but sometimes Wookieepedia is incomplete and I haven't read all the literature. It was used in Legends, but was gene therapy used in the [new canon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars/80098#80098)?

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gene_therapy

Comment: Does manipulating the clones in AotC so that they grow fast and have to follow orders count as gene therapy?

Comment: Huh. I guess that could be but that's more genetic engineering. Gene therapy is fixing diseases.

Comment: I'm a couple books short of finishing the new canon, but I think the answer is "No". That's said, it is very hard to prove a negative enough for a full answer here.