# What does Anakin Skywalker look like as a ghost in canon?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi

Under Disney canon, what does the Force ghost Anakin Skywalker look like? The 19 year old Anakin, before he was consumed and "killed" by Darth Vader, or the 45 year old un-Mustafar'ed version of Anakin had he remained in the light?

Comment: I think the real question you are asking is where the updated versions of the OT stand in Disney canon, which is kinda answered [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars).  "along with any deleted scenes (from the theatrical films), **earlier theatrical versions of the films**, commentaries, interview quotes, making-of documentaries, behind-the-scenes documentaries, concept art books and previous versions of the scripts are now all considered to be "Legends" properties."

Comment: I am not 100% sure but it seems the *latest* versions released are the *canon* ones.

Comment: @Skooba - This is specifically answered in my answer about canonicity. The Bluray edition is the definitive edition. All other versions before that are non-canon unless they agree with that edition.

Comment: Voting to reopen; the proposed duplicate explains the rules by which one would answer this question, but does not actually answer it or provide the necessary information with which to answer it.  (Specifically, it doesn't say which Anakin appears in the Bluray version.)

Comment: It does answer the question in saying "It looks like the Anakin that appears in the Bluray version"

Comment: @HarryJohnston - The question looks like a question about Anakin, but it ultimately boils down to "*which version of the films is the current acme from a canon perspective*" and that's been both asked and answered in the duplicate.

Comment: @Edlothiad, but I don't *own* the Bluray version, so how am I supposed to know which one that is?

Comment: Ask a question of what Anakin looked like in the blue Ray version, it's also covered below, now. This question, is still asking about the canonicty of works. Not his specific appearance.

Comment: Voting to reopen. The supposed duplicate provides no information about the appearance of Anakin's ghost. As @HarryJohnston points out, the supposed duplicate explains the rules for answering the question (i.e. the ghost looks however it looks in the Blu-ray version) but doesn't answer the question which I will quote **in full**: *Under Disney canon, what does the Force ghost Anakin Skywalker look like? The 19 year old Anakin, before he was consumed and "killed" by Darth Vader, or the 45 year old un-Mustafar'ed version of Anakin had he remained in the light?*

Comment: I hope people will stop branding New Canon as "Disney" Canon. Disney had no say in what's canon or not. That responsibility lies with Lucasfilm alone.

Comment: I'm at a loss why this has been reopened. The question of which version of the film is canon is dealt with [in the dupe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-is-canonicity-of-derivative-works-determined-for-star-wars?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Blackwood - The problem is that since the dupe covers which version is canon, the only part of the question that's not a dupe is the question of which 'Anakin head' appears in the Bluray version. Note that both existing answers essentially replicate information that's in the duplicate, just in less detail.

Comment: Furthermore, the user is aware what the different Anakins look like. That's not what he's asking. He wants to know which of the two is the correct one. Which is a canon question. Not a question about pictures of Anakin.

Answer (score 5):

As explained [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Canon), when the updated versions of the films contradict the originals, the newer versions "win". Therefore, in canon, the young Anakin appears. Of course, a lot of purists will argue with this, but that's how it is by the rules of canon.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is George Lucas retconned the end of ROTJ to put young Anakin in, and remove old Anakin

## Original

[image]

## Special Editon

[image]

So... which version is canon? Disney has more or less tiptoed around the issue. There's nothing anywhere that says which version is canon to Disney, likely because they would anger a ton of fans on either side. The [last official word from Leland Chee](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Canon), who was the original canon director, said this in 2008, when the Special Edition was the only one in release (emphasis mine)

> Anything not in the **current version** of the films is irrelevant to Film only continuity

So, without a contradicting statement from Disney (which there doesn't appear to be one) the young Anakin is the canon version.

Comment: This is simply incorrect. The bluray version of the original trilogy is stated to be the "correct" and fully canon version.

Comment: @Valorum Sorry that wasn't clear he was referring to the Special Edition (edited to reflect that). The first blu-ray version was released under Lucas, not Disney. So Disney still has no official position

Comment: @Machavity If they have not stated a position, then the last stated position by the previous canon owner continues to be the canon.

Comment: @Paul Which is what I said...

Comment: @Machavity - The bluray edition is described as "_definitive_" on the cover.

Comment: Does anyone else think Anakin looks kind of evil in the second version?  I do hope he's not a Sith-ghost of some sort. :-)

Comment: Why would **Disney** had to say anything? Disney never set the Canon. All canon/non-canon definition gets set by **Lucasfilm Story Group**. Much like no one say "Disney MCU", because what belongs in the MCU is Marvel's responsibility.

Comment: @pepoluan - The Story Group is something of a figleaf. Its reps include members of LucasFilm, sure, but it primarily consists of Disney reps.

Comment: @Valorum The LSG is a division of LFL. It has 11 members. ALL of them are LFL employees. I don't know where you got the info that the LSG "**_primarily_** consists of Disney reps", but that is plain wrong.